# Showing posts by collection of specific terms and texonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts, terms, custom-post-types

i have a custom post type name 'business' and taxonomy 'business-category'. now i want to show posts for some specific terms suppost, term1, term2, term3 etc. The following code is working for me but for only one term.

```
  $args=array(
    'taxonomy' => 'business-category',
    'term' => 'term1',
    'post_type' => 'business',
    'orderby'=> 'rand',
    );
  query_posts($args);
```

I need to pass array of terms. When i try to pass array of terms instead of one term it not working :(

```
   $args=array(
    'taxonomy' => 'business-category',
    'term' => array('term1', 'term2', 'term3'),
    'post_type' => 'business',
    'orderby'=> 'rand',
    );
  query_posts($args);
```

I also want to know how can i show post if i want to show from multiple taxonomy as well.

Thanks!

---

Resolved:

the query args will be:

```
    $args=array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                          array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'business-category',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array( 'bars', 'restaurants' )
                           )
          );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the array will work using terms, rather than term (plural)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Has a lot of useful info for mutiple terms/multiple taxonomies

but basically look into the tax_query item, specifically AND or OR operators. It's all explained there pretty well