# How to pass taxonomy terms to WP_Query along with $args?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms

I created a cpt and custom taxonomy associated with it. Lets say custom taxonomy name is Sports. I added terms to it - football, basketball.

Now, i want to fetch post titles tagged under football and basketball separately on same page.(Note:- i am using a custom page template to show list of articles from CPT).

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'sports',
      'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'sports_category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'football'
           ),
   ),
);

$myquery = new WP_Query($args);
```

So, i have successfully fetched posts for football, but if i want to fetch posts for basketball, do i have to create another query with 'terms' => 'basketball'?

Is there anyway to pass 'terms' dynamically in WP_Query along with set $args so that i don't have to write same arguments twice.

What i can think of a solution is creating a function and then storing terms in a variable which will get its value from value passed while calling function.

I want to know WP specific or efficient sokution.

Comment: Where (on which template) are you running this query?

Comment: I have created a custom template to show Post titles from cpt.

Comment: Look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545). You can do the same, you just need to change the code slightly to make use `wp_get_post_terms` instead of `get_the_category()`

Comment: I think this link could be interesting:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15040/showing-posts-by-collection-of-specific-terms-and-texonomy

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following

```
              $thiscat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();//put this code

              $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'sports',
               'tax_query' => array(
               array(
                 'taxonomy' => 'sports_category',
                 'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $thiscat->slug // Pass this to slug
           ),
     ),
 );

 $myquery = new WP_Query($args);
```

then you can able to fetch post titles tagged under football and basketball separately on same page.